# QML Image does not stretch/fit SVG

Tags: qt, svg, qml

I have this SVG image:

[image]

and I want to stretch (or fit) inside a QML Image.
I wrote this code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 250
    height: 250
    color: "yellow" // just to see the actual area

    Image {
        id: image
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 250
        height: 250
        source: "file:///home/mark/headphones.svg"
        sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
        fillMode: Image.Stretch
    }
}
```

Here the result:

[image]

Using `fillMode: Image.Stretch` or `fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit` I expect the image would actually fit the constraint of the desired size.

What am I missing here?

I'm run Qt 6.2.0 on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.

### UPDATE

Here the source code of the SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg11"
   height="100%"
   width="100%"
   version="1.0">
  <metadata
     id="metadata15">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs3">
    <pattern
       y="0"
       x="0"
       height="6"
       width="6"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       id="WMFhbasepattern" />
  </defs>
  <path
     id="path5"
     d="  M 25.074798,99.853263   L 25.097666,99.07575   L 25.131968,98.309671   L 25.200572,97.555026   L 25.292044,96.788947   L 25.417818,96.034302   L 25.56646,95.279657   L 25.749404,94.525012   L 25.943783,93.793235   L 26.172463,93.061458   L 26.435445,92.329681   L 26.709862,91.620772   L 27.01858,90.911863   L 27.350167,90.225822   L 27.704621,89.539781   L 28.081944,88.876608   L 28.482134,88.213435   L 28.905193,87.584564   L 29.362554,86.955693   L 29.831348,86.34969   L 30.323011,85.755121   L 30.837542,85.183421   L 31.363506,84.623154   L 31.923773,84.085755   L 32.495474,83.571224   L 33.090043,83.079562   L 33.696046,82.599333   L 34.324917,82.153406   L 34.965222,81.718914   L 35.61696,81.318723   L 36.291567,80.929967   L 36.966174,80.575512   L 37.663649,80.243926   L 38.372558,79.935207   L 39.092901,79.649357   L 39.824678,79.397808   L 40.556455,79.157694   L 41.299667,78.963316   L 42.054312,78.780372   L 42.808957,78.631729   L 43.563602,78.505955   L 44.329681,78.403049   L 45.107194,78.334445   L 45.873273,78.300143   L 46.639352,78.288709   L 47.416865,78.300143   L 48.182944,78.334445   L 48.937589,78.403049   L 49.703668,78.505955   L 50.458313,78.620295   L 51.212959,78.780372   L 51.967604,78.951882   L 52.699381,79.157694   L 53.431158,79.386374   L 54.162935,79.637923   L 54.871844,79.912339   L 55.580753,80.221058   L 56.266794,80.552644   L 56.952835,80.907099   L 57.627442,81.284421   L 58.279181,81.684612   L 58.919485,82.119104   L 59.536922,82.565031   L 60.142925,83.033826   L 60.737494,83.525488   L 61.309195,84.040019   L 61.869462,84.577418   L 62.40686,85.126251   L 62.921391,85.697951   L 63.413054,86.29252   L 63.893283,86.898523   L 64.339209,87.527394   L 64.773702,88.167699   L 65.173892,88.819438   L 65.562649,89.494045   L 65.917103,90.180086   L 66.24869,90.866127   L 66.557408,91.575036   L 66.843259,92.295379   L 67.106241,93.027156   L 67.334921,93.758933   L 67.540734,94.502144   L 67.712244,95.256789   L 67.860886,96.011434   L 67.98666,96.777513   L 68.089566,97.543592   L 68.158171,98.309671   L 68.192473,99.07575   L 68.203907,99.853263   L 68.203907,135.55026   L 68.192473,136.31634   L 68.158171,137.08242   L 68.089566,137.8485   L 67.98666,138.60314   L 67.87232,139.36922   L 67.723678,140.12387   L 67.540734,140.86708   L 67.334921,141.61029   L 67.106241,142.34207   L 66.854693,143.06241   L 66.580276,143.77132   L 66.271558,144.48023   L 65.939971,145.1777   L 65.585517,145.85231   L 65.208194,146.52692   L 64.808004,147.17866   L 64.373511,147.81896   L 63.927585,148.4364   L 63.45879,149.0424   L 62.967127,149.63697   L 62.452596,150.20867   L 61.915198,150.76894   L 61.366365,151.30634   L 60.794664,151.82087   L 60.200095,152.31253   L 59.594092,152.79276   L 58.965222,153.23869   L 58.324917,153.67318   L 57.673178,154.07337   L 56.998571,154.46212   L 56.31253,154.81658   L 55.626489,155.14817   L 54.91758,155.45688   L 54.197237,155.74273   L 53.46546,156.00572   L 52.733683,156.2344   L 51.990472,156.44021   L 51.235827,156.61172   L 50.481182,156.7718   L 49.715102,156.88614   L 48.960457,156.98904   L 48.182944,157.05765   L 47.416865,157.09195   L 46.639352,157.11482   L 45.873273,157.09195   L 45.107194,157.05765   L 44.341115,156.98904   L 43.58647,156.88614   L 42.820391,156.7718   L 42.07718,156.62315   L 41.322535,156.44021   L 40.579323,156.24583   L 39.847546,156.01715   L 39.127203,155.75417   L 38.418294,155.47975   L 37.709385,155.17103   L 37.01191,154.83945   L 36.337303,154.48499   L 35.662697,154.10767   L 35.010958,153.70748   L 34.370653,153.28442   L 33.753216,152.82706   L 33.147213,152.35827   L 32.552644,151.8666   L 31.980943,151.35207   L 31.420677,150.82611   L 30.883278,150.26584   L 30.368747,149.69414   L 29.877084,149.09957   L 29.396856,148.49357   L 28.950929,147.8647   L 28.516436,147.22439   L 28.116246,146.57265   L 27.727489,145.89805   L 27.373035,145.22344   L 27.041448,144.52596   L 26.73273,143.81706   L 26.446879,143.09671   L 26.183897,142.36494   L 25.955217,141.63316   L 25.749404,140.88995   L 25.577894,140.1353   L 25.417818,139.38066   L 25.303478,138.62601   L 25.200572,137.85993   L 25.131968,137.08242   L 25.097666,136.31634   L 25.074798,135.55026   L 25.074798,99.853263  z "
     style="fill:#000000;fill-rule:evenodd;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;" />
  <path
     id="path7"
     d="  M 114.72892,99.853263   L 114.75179,99.07575   L 114.78609,98.309671   L 114.85469,97.555026   L 114.9576,96.788947   L 115.07194,96.034302   L 115.22058,95.279657   L 115.40353,94.525012   L 115.5979,93.793235   L 115.82658,93.061458   L 116.08957,92.329681   L 116.36398,91.620772   L 116.6727,90.911863   L 117.00429,90.225822   L 117.35874,89.539781   L 117.73606,88.876608   L 118.13626,88.213435   L 118.57075,87.584564   L 119.01667,86.955693   L 119.48547,86.34969   L 119.97713,85.755121   L 120.49166,85.183421   L 121.02906,84.623154   L 121.57789,84.085755   L 122.1496,83.571224   L 122.74416,83.079562   L 123.35017,82.599333   L 123.97904,82.153406   L 124.61934,81.718914   L 125.27108,81.318723   L 125.94569,80.929967   L 126.63173,80.575512   L 127.31777,80.243926   L 128.02668,79.935207   L 128.74702,79.649357   L 129.4788,79.397808   L 130.21058,79.157694   L 130.95379,78.963316   L 131.70843,78.780372   L 132.46308,78.631729   L 133.21772,78.505955   L 133.9838,78.403049   L 134.76131,78.334445   L 135.52739,78.300143   L 136.30491,78.288709   L 137.07099,78.300143   L 137.83707,78.334445   L 138.60314,78.403049   L 139.35779,78.505955   L 140.12387,78.620295   L 140.86708,78.780372   L 141.62172,78.951882   L 142.36494,79.157694   L 143.09671,79.386374   L 143.81706,79.637923   L 144.52596,79.912339   L 145.23487,80.221058   L 145.93235,80.552644   L 146.60696,80.907099   L 147.28156,81.284421   L 147.9333,81.684612   L 148.57361,82.119104   L 149.19104,82.565031   L 149.79705,83.033826   L 150.39162,83.525488   L 150.96332,84.040019   L 151.52358,84.577418   L 152.06098,85.126251   L 152.57551,85.697951   L 153.06717,86.29252   L 153.5474,86.898523   L 153.99333,87.527394   L 154.42782,88.167699   L 154.82801,88.819438   L 155.21677,89.494045   L 155.57122,90.180086   L 155.90281,90.866127   L 156.21153,91.575036   L 156.49738,92.295379   L 156.76036,93.027156   L 156.98904,93.758933   L 157.19485,94.502144   L 157.36636,95.256789   L 157.51501,96.011434   L 157.64078,96.777513   L 157.74369,97.543592   L 157.81229,98.309671   L 157.84659,99.07575   L 157.86946,99.853263   L 157.86946,135.55026   L 157.84659,136.31634   L 157.81229,137.08242   L 157.74369,137.8485   L 157.64078,138.60314   L 157.52644,139.36922   L 157.3778,140.12387   L 157.19485,140.86708   L 157.00048,141.61029   L 156.7718,142.34207   L 156.50881,143.06241   L 156.2344,143.77132   L 155.92568,144.48023   L 155.59409,145.1777   L 155.23964,145.85231   L 154.86232,146.52692   L 154.46212,147.17866   L 154.03907,147.81896   L 153.58171,148.4364   L 153.11291,149.0424   L 152.62125,149.63697   L 152.10672,150.20867   L 151.56932,150.76894   L 151.02049,151.30634   L 150.44879,151.82087   L 149.85422,152.31253   L 149.24821,152.79276   L 148.61934,153.23869   L 147.97904,153.67318   L 147.3273,154.07337   L 146.65269,154.46212   L 145.96665,154.81658   L 145.28061,155.14817   L 144.5717,155.45688   L 143.85136,155.74273   L 143.11958,156.00572   L 142.3878,156.2344   L 141.64459,156.44021   L 140.88995,156.61172   L 140.1353,156.7718   L 139.38066,156.88614   L 138.61458,156.98904   L 137.83707,157.05765   L 137.07099,157.09195   L 136.30491,157.11482   L 135.52739,157.09195   L 134.76131,157.05765   L 133.99524,156.98904   L 133.24059,156.88614   L 132.48595,156.7718   L 131.7313,156.62315   L 130.97666,156.44021   L 130.23344,156.24583   L 129.50167,156.01715   L 128.78132,155.75417   L 128.07242,155.47975   L 127.36351,155.17103   L 126.66603,154.83945   L 125.99142,154.48499   L 125.31682,154.10767   L 124.66508,153.70748   L 124.02477,153.28442   L 123.40734,152.82706   L 122.80133,152.35827   L 122.20677,151.8666   L 121.63506,151.35207   L 121.0748,150.82611   L 120.5374,150.26584   L 120.02287,149.69414   L 119.53121,149.09957   L 119.05098,148.49357   L 118.60505,147.8647   L 118.17056,147.22439   L 117.77037,146.57265   L 117.38161,145.89805   L 117.02716,145.22344   L 116.69557,144.52596   L 116.38685,143.81706   L 116.101,143.09671   L 115.83802,142.36494   L 115.60934,141.63316   L 115.40353,140.88995   L 115.23202,140.1353   L 115.08337,139.38066   L 114.9576,138.62601   L 114.85469,137.85993   L 114.78609,137.08242   L 114.75179,136.31634   L 114.72892,135.55026   L 114.72892,99.853263  z "
     style="fill:#000000;fill-rule:evenodd;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;" />
  <path
     id="path9"
     d="  M 13.332063,126.6546   L 13.332063,83.55979   L 13.686517,76.264888   L 14.887089,69.427346   L 16.888042,62.818485   L 19.666508,56.449738   L 23.165317,50.355407   L 27.327299,44.592663   L 32.152454,39.150071   L 37.503573,34.16484   L 43.41496,29.568366   L 49.760838,25.486422   L 56.518342,21.919009   L 63.607432,18.934731   L 70.993807,16.533587   L 78.563125,14.795617   L 86.315388,13.720819   L 94.113387,13.354931   L 100.505,13.732253   L 106.99952,14.864221   L 113.59695,16.716532   L 120.19438,19.254883   L 126.70033,22.422106   L 133.02334,26.161029   L 139.10624,30.448785   L 144.84612,35.205336   L 150.17437,40.396379   L 154.97666,45.907575   L 159.23011,51.750357   L 162.83182,57.810386   L 165.7132,64.019057   L 167.83992,70.330634   L 169.1434,76.699381   L 169.6122,83.319676   L 169.6122,126.6546   L 182.94426,126.6546   L 182.94426,82.850881   L 182.38399,74.892806   L 180.73749,66.866127   L 178.1191,59.068128   L 174.63173,51.567413   L 170.36684,44.398285   L 165.42735,37.606479   L 159.85898,31.214864   L 153.77608,25.292044   L 147.22439,19.860886   L 140.28394,14.967127   L 133.01191,10.656503   L 125.49976,7.0090519   L 117.79323,4.0476417   L 109.9495,1.8523106   L 102.04859,0.46879466   L 94.204859,0   L 85.091949,0.4230586   L 76.161982,1.6579323   L 67.426394,3.6817532   L 58.953788,6.4259171   L 50.801334,9.867556   L 43.037637,13.960934   L 35.696999,18.683182   L 28.870891,23.977132   L 22.559314,29.86565   L 16.922344,36.234397   L 11.948547,43.117675   L 7.740829,50.446879   L 4.3563602,58.199142   L 1.8866127,66.340162   L 0.41162458,74.7899   L 0,83.251072   L 0,126.6546   L 13.332063,126.6546  z "
     style="fill:#000000;fill-rule:nonzero;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;" />
</svg>
```

Comment: does your headphones.svg file have a viewBox attribute on its root svg element?

Comment: @RobertLongson, question updated with the source code of the SVG file

Comment: So, the answer to my initial comment is no it doesn't, and then your answer is that you'd need to add one with appropriate values.

Comment: What are the "appropriate values"? I tried to add `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` but nothing has changed.

Comment: You might want to try viewBox="0 0 200 200" based on the coordinates in the path. (FWIW - that's pretty messed up SVG - using tens of line segments to draw arcs.)

Comment: Did you used `fillMode: Image.Fit` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your SVG File has a problem :

I update something in your code too :

```
Rectangle {
    width: 250
    height: 250
    color: "yellow" // just to see the actual area

    Image {
        id:img
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "img.svg"
        sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
        fillMode: Image.Stretch

    }
}
```

**SVG :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   id="svg11"
   height="166"
   width="200"
   version="1.0"
   sodipodi:docname="img.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.1 (ce6663b3b7, 2021-05-25)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview9"
     pagecolor="#505050"
     bordercolor="#eeeeee"
     borderopacity="1"
     inkscape:pageshadow="0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="1.2280088"
     inkscape:cx="144.13578"
     inkscape:cy="67.996257"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="670"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="27"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg11" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata15">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs3">
    <pattern
       y="0"
       x="0"
       height="6"
       width="6"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       id="WMFhbasepattern" />
  </defs>
  <path
     id="path5"
     d="m 34.080029,104.54594 0.02287,-0.77751 0.0343,-0.76608 0.0686,-0.75465 0.09147,-0.76607 0.125774,-0.75465 0.148642,-0.754644 0.182944,-0.754645 0.194379,-0.731777 0.22868,-0.731777 0.262982,-0.731777 0.274417,-0.708909 0.308718,-0.708909 0.331587,-0.686041 0.354454,-0.686041 0.377323,-0.663173 0.40019,-0.663173 0.423059,-0.628871 0.457361,-0.628871 0.468794,-0.606003 0.491663,-0.594569 0.514531,-0.5717 0.525964,-0.560267 0.560267,-0.537399 0.571701,-0.514531 0.594569,-0.491662 0.606003,-0.480229 0.628871,-0.445927 0.640305,-0.434492 0.651738,-0.400191 0.674607,-0.388756 0.674607,-0.354455 0.697475,-0.331586 0.708909,-0.308719 0.720343,-0.28585 0.731777,-0.251549 0.731777,-0.240114 0.743212,-0.194378 0.754645,-0.182944 0.754645,-0.148643 0.754645,-0.125774 0.766079,-0.102906 0.777513,-0.0686 0.766079,-0.0343 0.766079,-0.01143 0.777513,0.01143 0.766079,0.0343 0.754645,0.0686 0.766079,0.102906 0.754645,0.11434 0.754646,0.160077 0.754645,0.17151 0.731777,0.205812 0.731777,0.22868 0.731777,0.251549 0.708909,0.274416 0.708909,0.308719 0.686041,0.331586 0.686041,0.354455 0.674607,0.377322 0.651739,0.400191 0.640304,0.434492 0.617437,0.445927 0.606003,0.468795 0.594569,0.491662 0.571701,0.514531 0.560267,0.537399 0.537398,0.548833 0.514531,0.5717 0.491663,0.594569 0.480229,0.606003 0.445926,0.628871 0.434493,0.640305 0.40019,0.651739 0.388757,0.674607 0.354454,0.686041 0.331587,0.686041 0.308718,0.708909 0.285851,0.720343 0.262982,0.731777 0.22868,0.731777 0.205813,0.743211 0.17151,0.754645 0.148642,0.754642 0.125774,0.76608 0.102906,0.76608 0.0686,0.76608 0.0343,0.76608 0.01143,0.77751 v 35.697 l -0.01143,0.76608 -0.0343,0.76608 -0.0686,0.76608 -0.102906,0.75464 -0.11434,0.76608 -0.148642,0.75465 -0.182944,0.74321 -0.205813,0.74321 -0.22868,0.73178 -0.251548,0.72034 -0.274417,0.70891 -0.308718,0.70891 -0.331587,0.69747 -0.354454,0.67461 -0.377323,0.67461 -0.40019,0.65174 -0.434493,0.6403 -0.445926,0.61744 -0.468795,0.606 -0.491663,0.59457 -0.514531,0.5717 -0.537398,0.56027 -0.548833,0.5374 -0.571701,0.51453 -0.594569,0.49166 -0.606003,0.48023 -0.62887,0.44593 -0.640305,0.43449 -0.651739,0.40019 -0.674607,0.38875 -0.686041,0.35446 -0.686041,0.33159 -0.708909,0.30871 -0.720343,0.28585 -0.731777,0.26299 -0.731777,0.22868 -0.743211,0.20581 -0.754645,0.17151 -0.754645,0.16008 -0.76608,0.11434 -0.754645,0.1029 -0.777513,0.0686 -0.766079,0.0343 -0.777513,0.0229 -0.766079,-0.0229 -0.766079,-0.0343 -0.766079,-0.0686 -0.754645,-0.1029 -0.766079,-0.11434 -0.743211,-0.14865 -0.754645,-0.18294 -0.743212,-0.19438 -0.731777,-0.22868 -0.720343,-0.26298 -0.708909,-0.27442 -0.708909,-0.30872 -0.697475,-0.33158 -0.674607,-0.35446 -0.674606,-0.37732 -0.651739,-0.40019 -0.640305,-0.42306 -0.617437,-0.45736 -0.606003,-0.46879 -0.594569,-0.49167 -0.571701,-0.51453 -0.560266,-0.52596 -0.537399,-0.56027 -0.514531,-0.5717 -0.491663,-0.59457 -0.480228,-0.606 -0.445927,-0.62887 -0.434493,-0.64031 -0.40019,-0.65174 -0.388757,-0.6746 -0.354454,-0.67461 -0.331587,-0.69748 -0.308718,-0.7089 -0.285851,-0.72035 -0.262982,-0.73177 -0.22868,-0.73178 -0.205813,-0.74321 -0.17151,-0.75465 -0.160076,-0.75464 -0.11434,-0.75465 -0.102906,-0.76608 -0.0686,-0.77751 -0.0343,-0.76608 -0.02287,-0.76608 z"
     style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" />
  <path
     id="path7"
     d="m 123.73415,104.54594 0.0229,-0.77751 0.0343,-0.76608 0.0686,-0.75465 0.10291,-0.76607 0.11434,-0.75465 0.14864,-0.754644 0.18295,-0.754645 0.19437,-0.731777 0.22868,-0.731777 0.26299,-0.731777 0.27441,-0.708909 0.30872,-0.708909 0.33159,-0.686041 0.35445,-0.686041 0.37732,-0.663173 0.4002,-0.663173 0.43449,-0.628871 0.44592,-0.628871 0.4688,-0.606003 0.49166,-0.594569 0.51453,-0.5717 0.5374,-0.560267 0.54883,-0.537399 0.57171,-0.514531 0.59456,-0.491662 0.60601,-0.480229 0.62887,-0.445927 0.6403,-0.434492 0.65174,-0.400191 0.67461,-0.388756 0.68604,-0.354455 0.68604,-0.331586 0.70891,-0.308719 0.72034,-0.28585 0.73178,-0.251549 0.73178,-0.240114 0.74321,-0.194378 0.75464,-0.182944 0.75465,-0.148643 0.75464,-0.125774 0.76608,-0.102906 0.77751,-0.0686 0.76608,-0.0343 0.77752,-0.01143 0.76608,0.01143 0.76608,0.0343 0.76607,0.0686 0.75465,0.102906 0.76608,0.11434 0.74321,0.160077 0.75464,0.17151 0.74322,0.205812 0.73177,0.22868 0.72035,0.251549 0.7089,0.274416 0.70891,0.308719 0.69748,0.331586 0.67461,0.354455 0.6746,0.377322 0.65174,0.400191 0.64031,0.434492 0.61743,0.445927 0.60601,0.468795 0.59457,0.491662 0.5717,0.514531 0.56026,0.537399 0.5374,0.548833 0.51453,0.5717 0.49166,0.594569 0.48023,0.606003 0.44593,0.628871 0.43449,0.640305 0.40019,0.651739 0.38876,0.674607 0.35445,0.686041 0.33159,0.686041 0.30872,0.708909 0.28585,0.720343 0.26298,0.731777 0.22868,0.731777 0.20581,0.743211 0.17151,0.754645 0.14865,0.754642 0.12577,0.76608 0.10291,0.76608 0.0686,0.76608 0.0343,0.76608 0.0229,0.77751 v 35.697 l -0.0229,0.76608 -0.0343,0.76608 -0.0686,0.76608 -0.10291,0.75464 -0.11434,0.76608 -0.14864,0.75465 -0.18295,0.74321 -0.19437,0.74321 -0.22868,0.73178 -0.26299,0.72034 -0.27441,0.70891 -0.30872,0.70891 -0.33159,0.69747 -0.35445,0.67461 -0.37732,0.67461 -0.4002,0.65174 -0.42305,0.6403 -0.45736,0.61744 -0.4688,0.606 -0.49166,0.59457 -0.51453,0.5717 -0.5374,0.56027 -0.54883,0.5374 -0.5717,0.51453 -0.59457,0.49166 -0.60601,0.48023 -0.62887,0.44593 -0.6403,0.43449 -0.65174,0.40019 -0.67461,0.38875 -0.68604,0.35446 -0.68604,0.33159 -0.70891,0.30871 -0.72034,0.28585 -0.73178,0.26299 -0.73178,0.22868 -0.74321,0.20581 -0.75464,0.17151 -0.75465,0.16008 -0.75464,0.11434 -0.76608,0.1029 -0.77751,0.0686 -0.76608,0.0343 -0.76608,0.0229 -0.77752,-0.0229 -0.76608,-0.0343 -0.76607,-0.0686 -0.75465,-0.1029 -0.75464,-0.11434 -0.75465,-0.14865 -0.75464,-0.18294 -0.74322,-0.19438 -0.73177,-0.22868 -0.72035,-0.26298 -0.7089,-0.27442 -0.70891,-0.30872 -0.69748,-0.33158 -0.67461,-0.35446 -0.6746,-0.37732 -0.65174,-0.40019 -0.64031,-0.42306 -0.61743,-0.45736 -0.60601,-0.46879 -0.59456,-0.49167 -0.57171,-0.51453 -0.56026,-0.52596 -0.5374,-0.56027 -0.51453,-0.5717 -0.49166,-0.59457 -0.48023,-0.606 -0.44593,-0.62887 -0.43449,-0.64031 -0.40019,-0.65174 -0.38876,-0.6746 -0.35445,-0.67461 -0.33159,-0.69748 -0.30872,-0.7089 -0.28585,-0.72035 -0.26298,-0.73177 -0.22868,-0.73178 -0.20581,-0.74321 -0.17151,-0.75465 -0.14865,-0.75464 -0.12577,-0.75465 -0.10291,-0.76608 -0.0686,-0.77751 -0.0343,-0.76608 -0.0229,-0.76608 z"
     style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" />
  <path
     id="path9"
     d="M 22.337294,131.34728 V 88.252469 l 0.354454,-7.294902 1.200572,-6.837542 2.000953,-6.608861 2.778466,-6.368747 3.498809,-6.094331 4.161982,-5.762744 4.825155,-5.442592 5.351119,-4.985231 5.911387,-4.596474 6.345878,-4.081944 6.757504,-3.567413 7.08909,-2.984278 7.386375,-2.401144 7.569318,-1.73797 7.752263,-1.074798 7.798001,-0.365888 6.39161,0.377322 6.49452,1.131968 6.59743,1.852311 6.59743,2.538351 6.50595,3.167223 6.32301,3.738923 6.0829,4.287756 5.73988,4.756551 5.32825,5.191043 4.80229,5.511196 4.25345,5.842782 3.60171,6.060029 2.88138,6.208671 2.12672,6.311577 1.30348,6.368747 0.4688,6.620295 v 43.334925 h 13.33206 V 87.54356 l -0.56027,-7.958075 -1.6465,-8.026679 -2.61839,-7.797999 -3.48737,-7.500715 -4.26489,-7.169128 -4.93949,-6.791806 -5.56837,-6.391615 -6.0829,-5.92282 -6.55169,-5.431158 -6.94045,-4.893759 -7.27203,-4.310624 -7.51215,-3.647451 -7.70653,-2.9614098 -7.84373,-2.1953311 -7.90091,-1.383516 -7.84373,-0.4687946 -9.11291,0.4230586 -8.929967,1.2348737 -8.735588,2.0238209 -8.472606,2.7441643 -8.152454,3.441638 -7.763697,4.093378 -7.340638,4.722248 -6.826108,5.29395 -6.311577,5.888518 -5.63697,6.368747 -4.973797,6.883278 -4.207718,7.329204 -3.384469,7.752263 -2.469748,8.14102 -1.4749878,8.449738 -0.4116246,8.461172 v 43.403529 z"
     style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" />
</svg>
```

**out put :**
[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly, the main problem was the incorrect settings of the `width` and `height` values, right? Actually, it was the only thing I changed to achieve the result above.

Comment: Yes , I also open svg in Inkscape and change it's width and height.